# Python - Reordering the final list in a list of lists and having all corresponding list indices change to the same index ordering

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists in python i.e.

`[[6.0, 3.0, 16.0, 3.0], [3.0, 2.0, 5.0, 7.0], [4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]]`

I then want to order the final list in the list of lists by ascending numerical size, but the change of order in the indexes of this list I want to be applied to the other corresponding indexes in the other lists within the list. For example,

`[[6.0, 3.0, 16.0, 3.0], [3.0, 2.0, 5.0, 7.0], [4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]]`

turns into

```
[[3.0, 16.0, 3.0, 6.0], [7.0, 5.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]
```

Apologies if this isn't worded greatly, I am rather new to python.

I have looked into using the zip and sorted functions however haven't been able to use them to the effect I want to.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to associate to each number in the list you are ordering to an incrementing index - and then use this incrementing index as target for each element in the previous lists.

```
def order_by_last(data):
     indexes = list(enumerate(data[-1]))
     indexes.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[1])
     new_list = [[sublist[index[0]] for index in indexes]   for sublist in data]
     return new_list
```

```
In [56]: order_by_last([[6.0, 3.0, 16.0, 3.0], [3.0, 2.0, 5.0, 7.0], [4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]])
Out[56]: [[3.0, 16.0, 3.0, 6.0], [7.0, 5.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are willing to use external libraries, but you need an argsort for this one from numpy [argsort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html). Note that the output is not a python list, but rather a numpy array (which can be converted though).

So you can get your result by doing the following:

```
# done list_of_lists
list_order = argsort(list_of_lists[-1])
new_list = []
for single_list in list_of_lists:
     buffer_list = []
     for position in list_order:
         buffer_list.append(single_list[position])
     new_list.append(buffer_list)
```

Keep in mind though that if your lists are different sizes, this might break.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = [[6.0, 3.0, 16.0, 3.0], [3.0, 2.0, 5.0, 7.0], [4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]]

>>> list(zip(*sorted((zip(*a)), key=lambda x: x[-1])))
[(3.0, 16.0, 3.0, 6.0), (7.0, 5.0, 2.0, 3.0), (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)]
```

I'm using two idioms here:

1. `zip(*list_of_lists)` acts as a matrix transposer by swapping rows and columns of the matrix, represented by a list of lists.
2. sorting the transposed list of lists by the value of the last element.

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a sorted list of indexes based on the last list, then recreate each other list based on these indexes.

```py
l = [[6.0, 3.0, 16.0, 3.0], [3.0, 2.0, 5.0, 7.0], [4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]]
indexes = sorted(range(len(l[-1])), key=lambda x:l[-1][x])
res = [[x[i] for i in indexes] for x in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use zip to restructure the list into columnwise tuples, sort them and then turn that back into original lists:

```
L = [[6.0, 3.0, 16.0, 3.0], [3.0, 2.0, 5.0, 7.0], [4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]]

R = [*map(list,zip(*sorted(zip(*L[::-1]))))][::-1]

# [[3.0, 16.0, 3.0, 6.0], [7.0, 5.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]]
```

Another way (much less efficient but perhaps more readable) is to sort each row based on the last row's corresponding values:

```
R = [ [v for _,v in sorted(zip(L[-1],r))] for r in L ]
```